# How to disable button permanently after click ,buttons created from server data using loops?

Tags: javascript, php, html, mysql

I have a list of buttons on a page that is created using a database, I would like to disable the user click button permanently. Button should be in diable mode after page load too.

```
<div class="panel-group" id="posts">  
            <?php  
            while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
            {  
            ?>  
              <button id='registedButton' type='button' onclick='getButtonDataId(this)' data-id=<?php echo $row["Acronym"]; ?>>Applied</button> 
             }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<div class="panel-group" id="posts">  
        <?php  
        while($row = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {  
        ?>  
          <button id='registedButton_<?php echo $row["Acronym"]; ?>' type='button' class="registedButton" data-id=<?php echo $row["Acronym"]; ?>>Applied</button> 
         <?php } ?>
```

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
   $(".registedButton").each(function() {
        var getCookieName = $(this).attr('id');
        if(getCookie(getCookieName)){
           $(this).prop('disabled',true);
        }
   });
});
$('.registedButton').on('click', function(e) {
 var cookieName = $(this).attr('id');
 var eCookie = setCookie(cookieName, 'setVal');
 e.preventDefault();
 $(this).prop('disabled',true);
});
</script>
```

Comment: Why you have changed thi id='registedButton_<?php echo $row["Acronym"]; ?>'

Comment: Will it disable particular button or every button.And moreover button should be disable after reloading too.

Comment: id='registedButton_<?php echo $row["Acronym"]; ?>' always should be unique one

Comment: you have to use setCookie('cookieName', cookieValue); if you need to maintain after reload...

Comment: My main aim is to achieve setCookie('cookieName', cookieValue); this with my code.

Comment: updated answer, please check

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).